# when i execute pandas-profiling package it won't return min, max and mean values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6, pandas-profiling, data-profiling

When i profiling the following data using **pandas-profiling==2.8.0** it won't return min, max and mean values.

> CSV data

**a,b,c**

12,2.5,0
12,4.7,5
33,5,4
44,44.21,67

> python code

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

def profile_report(data):
    dataset = data.select_dtypes(include=['int64', 'float64'])  
    profile=ProfileReport(dataset, minimal=True)
    json_data=profile.to_json()
    results = json.loads(json_data)
    print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',index_col=None)
    profile_report(df)
```

in some case it work properly and return min, max and mean values. but when i execute above csv data it won't return that values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a dataset with less elements than a given number (say 5), pandas-profiling assumes that your variable is categorical instead of interval.

Use the `vars.num.low_categorical_threshold` parameter to change this ([docs](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/rtd/pages/advanced_usage.html#variable-summary-settings))

Example:

```py
profile = ProfileReport(dataset, minimal=True, vars=dict(num={"low_categorical_threshold": 0}))
```